# getting '__getitem__' error in tokenizing in python

Tags: python, csv, nltk, tokenize, text-mining

I am trying to toknize word for text mining process. I have csv file. My textual data has been collected in column name 'Abstrac'. So I am trying to run the following code, but I get the error `'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

[image]

```
def get_tokens():
    with open('scopus (1).csv', 'r') as data:
        text = data['Abstract'].read()
        lowers = text.lower()
    #remove the punctuation using the character deletion step of translate
        no_punctuation = lowers.translate(None, string.punctuation)
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(no_punctuation)
    return tokens
tokens = get_tokens()
count = Counter(tokens)
print count.most_common(10)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e7af75d6fd69> in <module>()
      7         tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(no_punctuation)
      8     return tokens
----> 9 tokens = get_tokens()

<ipython-input-12-e7af75d6fd69> in get_tokens()
      1 def get_tokens():
      2     with open('scopus (1).csv', 'r') as data:
----> 3         text = data['Abstract'][i].read()
      4         lowers = text.lower()
      5     #remove the punctuation using the character deletion step of translate

TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `data` is just a file-like object, not a data structure produced by parsing the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = data['Abstract'][i].read()
```

Are you trying to read data only from the `Abstract` column?  If so, use the `csv.DictReader` class:

```
r = csv.DictReader(data)
for row in r:
    text = row['Abstract']
    #Process line by line
```